# Map (graph) of unsolved problems in different fields of mathematics

Tags: soft-question

*This is very much a soft question, and rather a general, quite fuzzy (and perhaps nonsense and/or impossible), idea I have. I have looked around as well as I can, and mostly I found some books with traditional lists and [this site](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/).*

Q.) **Does anyone know if there is anything close to fitting the following description:**

A graph of unsolved (possibly even some solved) problems in a specific area of mathematics (probably quite restricted), where we have names of the problems as nodes, and edges describing the relations between them.

I imagine such graphs existing perhaps for specific conjectures, and thus they would provide a good illustration of the work that needs to be done in order to solve it.

I also imagine these graphs to possibly be interactive (hyper linked perhaps), so that one could click on the nodes to get a graph of that problem and/or more information about the problem. The edges could possibly even be weighted, (and directed) to reflect the importance of that problem in relation to another.

(If not interactive then just a graph, and if not a graph, then just a detailed hyper linked database of unsolved problems, that also lists directly related problems together with their importance to that specific problem, but this is of course already close to [wikipedia's pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_mathematics).)

*The restriction mentioned in §1 under Q is of course just there for convenience. In a sense, the more problems such a graph would incorporate the better, however this puts a lot of requirements on the functionality of the graph, for it to be useful. Perhaps we could imagine a graph where only the most important problems (graded according to some rules) are visible at a single time. Clicking on a problem could open up a similar graph of that problem and so on.*

EDIT: I actually found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/796283/a-graph-of-all-of-mathematics?rq=1) thread now, via the 'related' list. I did not see this there while I was writing the question. This thread of course touches on several questions related to this one.

Comment: What are the edges of such a graph supposed to indicate?

Comment: So what you're essentially asking for is  essentially like the course-map from ocw.mit.edu but for solved and open problems in mathematics. I imagine that to be quite a formidable task, for it would probably be a very large graph/map.

Comment: @JohnBentin: Possibly a relation between problems P1 and P2 (of some sort), say that the truth of P2 implies something that can be used to show P1, this could perhaps indicated by a directed arrow P2->P1. But since there could be many such connections, this could be built up like a graph. This is all very fuzzy, I agree, and I am not very experienced in researching mathematics and/or proof theory.

Comment: @Nox: Yes, I agree, so it would probably be a better idea, as I mention, to restrict one self to perhaps a singe conjecture of certain interest or so. I was just curious to see if anyone knew of anything like this existing. But of course, the next best thing (better in some aspects) would be to have a hyper linked database, but with the additional listings of related theorems/conjectures. And is wikipedia the closest thing to that we have?